# Pushing to a different remote repository

Tags: git, push, git-remote

Let's say I have a local repository **A** and also I have access to remote repository **B**. These repositories are **completely different**! I want to push all files/commits etc... from **A** to **B** repository. 
So I did following git commands:

1. `git remote add origin <my remote git url>`
2. `git push origin master`

And I got the following error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

The reason of question is that I don't want to do `git pull` command because **B** repository taking up a lot of space (tons of gigabytes!) while **A** repository take couple of kilobytes.

Is there any way to push without a pull?

Comment: Push to a branch that does not exist in the remote.  (eg, create a new branch on the remote)

Comment: AFAIK you can’t “push files from A to B”. Commits are snapshots of all files, and commits are what get “pushed and pulled”. - but then this question doesn’t seem to be asking that

Answer (score 2):

Create a new branch on the remote:

```
git push origin master:my-branch
```

Then, on the remote, you'll probably want to add your work to the master branch.  One way to do that is:

```
git checkout my-branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge my-branch
```

Comment: Thank you! that's what i needed